# USB random write speed

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I recently got a kingston dtmicro 3.1 128gb I notice whenever writing to the USB the write speed keeps on changing from 80mbps to 0mbps every 3 seconds, how would I get a constant speed of 80mbps?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get different hardware. That SSD has a rated write speed of 15megabytes/sec.Kingston don't exactly broadcast the write speed on their spevs (they only talk about up to 80 megabits read speed ) but the Amazon listing talks about it - [https://www.amazon.com/Kingston-DataTraveler-64GB-Ultra-Small-DTMC3/dp/B00ZRHY9LM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZRHY9LM)

(As a relevant aside, Ive never come across a decent speed microsd or USB pen drive. At some point started using a USB SSD drive, and never looked back.)